# How to increase the partition of existing topic while using S3 sink connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, s3-kafka-connector

I am using S3 sink connector along with kafka connect and trying to load data to s3 . somehow I am unable to update or increase the size of topic partition and also cannot change offset.flush.timeout.ms value.
I am trying to add that in the S3 connector curl file which I am using but nothing updates.

```
{
    "name": "my-s3-sink3",
     "config": {
         "connector.class"               : "io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector",
         "tasks.max"                     : "1",
         "topics"                        : "mysource.topic",
         "s3.region"                     : "us-east-1",
         "s3.bucket.name"                : "topicbucket001",
         "s3.part.size"                  : "5242880",
         "flush.size"                    : "1",
         "key.converter"                 : "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
         "value.converter"               : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
         "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
         "storage.class"                 : "io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage",
         "format.class"                  : "io.confluent.connect.s3.format.json.JsonFormat",
         "partitioner.class"             : "io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner",
         "schema.compatibility"          : "NONE"
         "offset.flush.timeout.ms"        : 1000
         "topic.creation.default.replication.factor": 3,
         "topic.creation.default.partitions": 10,
         "topic.creation.default.compression.type": "snappy"
        }
    }
```

Comment: You spelled "flush" wrong and you need to use a prefix to update any consumer config properties in a connector, but also, this wouldn't prevent you from increasing partitions of the input topic. Also, sinks generally don't create topics, so you can remove the bottom properties

Comment: Hello @OneCricketeer Thanks for the update , so you mean like "consumer.offset.flush.timeout.ms" and "consumer.flush.size" ? But is it possible to create partitions for the topics since I have enabled auto.topics.creation to true in my kafka setup , so topic gets automatically created but I m unable to set partitions to that topic.

Comment: `flush.size` is a connector config, so doesn't need a prefix. I cannot recall if it's just `consumer.` or `consumer.override.`, but yes like that... And like I mentioned, consumers (or sinks) shouldn't be responsible for creating topics, only producers (or sources), so I don't think those properties do anything there... Specifically, if it did create a topic, it would have no data, so nothing would be written to S3 anyway. And again, this is unrelated to modification of partition size of the topic, so I'm not sure I understand the question title